# In spark streaming, what is the difference between foreach and foreachRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, dstream, bigdata

For example, how would

```
x.foreach(rdd => rdd.cache())
```

be different from

```
x.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.cache())
```

Note that `x` is a `DStream` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in work, foreach() [uses](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.scala#L641) foreachRDD. foreach() was deprecated and in Spark 2.0 this function is removed